# how to sum the values in similar group in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
alpha <- c(11,12,21,24,33,11,33)
group <- c("a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "c","d")

df <- data.frame(group,alpha)
df <- df[with(df, order(group)),]
```

I want to sum the values for each group and append the result in the dataframe but I'm not sure how to do it. The output will be something like the result below.

```
   group alpha sum
1     a    11  65
2     a    21  65
3     a    33  65
4     b    12  12
5     c    24  35
6     c    11  35
7     d    33  33
```

Comment: Sorry, there are some error and I edited already

Comment: `df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(alpha = sum(alpha)) %>% arrange(group)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` with `group_by` to calculate the sum and then `join` to append your original data.frame:

```
alpha <- c(11,12,21,24,33,11,33)
group <- c("a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "c","d")

df <- data.frame(group,alpha)
df <- df[with(df, order(group)),]

library(dplyr)
df_stat <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(alpha))

df <- df %>% 
  left_join(df_stat)

df
  group alpha sum
1     a    11  65
2     a    21  65
3     a    33  65
4     b    12  12
5     c    24  35
6     c    11  35
7     d    33  33
```